# Borderlands 2 GOTY co-op with original Borderlands 2 w/o DLCs

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm planning to buy the BL2 GOTY (Game of the Year) edition. Lets say I did that. My friend already owns the original BL2, but without any DLCs.

1. Can we play co-op?
2. If yes, can I play as Gaige or Psycho? (Which are characters not included in the original BL2)

Comment: I believe that as long as you host the game, your friend can play the dlc content that they don't have (if they log out in the area they might still have access until they leave the area), but I don't think they can created dlc only character class if they don't have the dlc.

Comment: @Krazer unless this was a more recent change that I'm unaware of, I do not believe this to be the case (the friend without DLC being able to join DLC areas).

Comment: Then can I choose Gaige or Psyco and play with my friend?

Comment: It would seem that they can't play any of the dlc areas or pickup any of the dlc weapons, if they don't have the dlc installed, but they can still play the regular campaign with your dlc characters, they just can't get into the dlc area regardless of who hosts the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to play cooperatively with your friend, bearing in mind that lacking the DLC, your friend probably can't join you in any DLC areas (Tiny Tina's, Mr. Torgue's, Sir Hammerlock's, Captain Scarlet).

However, any paid characters like Gaige or Psyco should not interfere - My friend has no issues connecting with me as I play mechromancer, while he owns neither, and I've played with plenty of Psyco's while having not purchased him.

I am, however, a little foggy on how some things might work out; like Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, with your DLC-lacking friend.

Additionally, your friend won't be able to use any DLC weapons that you may want to trade to him.

Comment: Really you can play as Gaige or Psyco when you don't have them, because of your friend have them?

Comment: Also they download extra files for display those area and classes?

Comment: I should clarify - You (the one with the DLC) can use the DLC characters, and they will not affect your ability to play cooperatively with your friend (Who, lacking DLC cannot play as them)

Comment: i thought my friend can choose DLC character too, guess i wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can  play as a DLC character in a host's game even if they don't have them, and vice-versa.  Your friend will not be able to go to any dlc areas nor use any of the weapons.  As to the level caps, someone who does not have UVHM 1 or 2 will still be able to play with you, they just won't level up after they hit whatever cap they have.